# Zend Framework 2 - View

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am developing an application using ZF2. I get confused by `Views`. In ZF1, i have initiated   a view object in bootstrapper and used it on all modules and views. How can i do the same thing using ZF2?

In ZF1, I have used the following sample codes in Bootstrapper.

```
$view = new Zend_view();
$view->sitePath = 'mysite.com';
```

I have to keep the sitename in a global object. I think, there is no registry in ZF2.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the official manual and become familiar with the way Zend Framework 2 works. Even if the manual might have lots of missing bits and pieces, the core concepts are explained very well.

- [Zend\View QuickStart (Section: Controllers and ViewModels)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#controllers-and-view-models)
- [Zend\View Manual Overview](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html#zend-view)

Going through this you'll notice, that there is a [Zend\View\Helper\BasePath](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#basepath-helper) present (which btw. remains true for ZF1, too), which absolutely fits the use-case you've described above.

Comment: I have checked the manual. It prints nothing. <?php echo $this->basePath(); ?> I want to keep my site path in a global object.

Comment: sorry, I can get the file's basepath with this code. <?php echo $this->basePath('file'); ?> But, I want to keep my site path in a global object. So, i can assign the site title, sitepath and constants in that place. And use that in entire application.

Comment: The output of `basePath()` will pretty much be just `/` which is absolutely fine. This is the root of your website. And when anybody copys the link via right click, the full URL will automatically be prepended by the browser itself. If you WANT to have it global, simply inside `module.config.php` put the basepath like `'sitepath' => 'http://domain.tld'`

Comment: Thanks. Where i have to define sitepath' => 'http://domain.tld' in module.config.php. I have defined in view_manager, view_helper and separate object like the above. i echoed $this->sitepath in views. Nothing in my views.